# How would one approximate the surface area of a curved shape as on these ETFE pillows?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, area, curves, surface-integrals

I need to get the surface area of these ETFE pillows:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are surely different types of modelization, some of them based on physics. Here is one based on a visually satisfying similarity. Indeed (white) cross sections appear to be well modelized by parabolas ($z=k(W^2-y^2)$); the way these coefficients $k$ vary as a function of $x$ is rather arbitrary; here we have taken:

$$z=f(x,y)=\underbrace{\frac{h}{W^2}  \sqrt{\cos(\pi \frac{x}{2L})}}_{k}(W^2-y^2) \ \ \text{for}  \ \ -L<x<L, \ -W<y<W $$

where $2L$ is the length and $2W$ the width of the mattress and $h$ the measured maximal height in the middle of the mattress.

[image]

It remains to use the following formula for the surface area (see [here](https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Etolya/surfacearea)):

$$A=\int_{x=-L}^L \int_{y=-W}^W \sqrt{1+\left(\partial f/\partial x\right)^2 + \left(\partial f/\partial y\right)^2}dx dy$$

For given values of $L$ and $W$, using a numerical software, one gets a numerical value for $A$.

Remarks: One could instead have considered NURBS surfaces.

Here is the family of parabolas with common roots $\pm a$ (here with $a=1$) with common equation $y=k(a^2-x^2)=k(a-x)(a+x)$. Here $k$ is linearly increasing. In the case of the mattress, $k$ must stay a long time almost constant then decrease rather sharply.

[image]

Comment: Hi I am a high school student who needs to use this information for a project and your answer was immensely helpful! That being said, I do need to simplify and would like to understand the parabolic modelling better. Could you recommend some resources (books, videos, web pages anything!) that I could use as well as your mentioned numerical software? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I am going to answer your question.

Comment: See the picture I just included.